# XPath selector for list item inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am using selenium to test a site. I am using XPath selector to get to an item. This is how the HTML looks:

```
<div id="boundlist-1051" class="x-boundlist list_cfg_cls x-boundlist-floating x-layer x-boundlist-default" tabindex="-1" style="left: 1096px; top: 318px; width: 370px; z-index: 29001; height: auto;">
    <div id="boundlist-1051-listEl" class="x-boundlist-list-ct" style="overflow: auto; height: auto;">
        <ul>
            <li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item">User name</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

From the upper most div which contains a class by name `list_cfg_cls`, I need to navigate to `> div > ui > li.`

This is what I am using but getting some error:

```
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class='list_cfg_cls')]/div/ul/li")).Click();
```

I am using XPath selector: "`//div[contains(@class='list_cfg_cls')]/div/ul/li`"

I will have only one item under list.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of using XPath [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) function is by passing 2 arguments, like so :

```
//div[contains(@class, 'list_cfg_cls')]/div/ul/li
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried this `By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'list_cfg_cls')]/div/ul/li")` but I am still not able to produce desired result.

Comment: then the problem is somewhere else, maybe selenium specific things (unfortunately I'm not familiar with selenium). As for the xpath against the HTML posted in question, it should work fine. See the demo here : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/4f6d37c6c1226d95959fce0473952896

Comment: @SharpCoder does `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'list_cfg_cls')]/div/ul/li"))` return a WebElement (not null)? If it does, the problem is not in finding element, but rather in clicking it.